# Trying the retrieve ID's data other page with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quick explain: Retrieving data from DB with search bar. So a couple of data retrieving due to the search. And after the search also I want to display each data in a single page by their ID. For example, lots of estates data are retrieving like: Estate_Name, Estate_Address etc in a html table.I want to put estate_name a link to go another page which just retrieve that ID's data.

I updated the problem with new codes, and getting this error now:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/show.blade.php)

This is controller:

```
    public function show($id)
    {

       $estates = allestates::findOrFail($id);
       return view('show')->with(['estates' => $estates]);

    }
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'PagesController@show');
```

also this the main.blade;

```
@foreach($estates as $estate)
    <tr class="even">
        <td>{{$estate->id}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->company_name, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td><a href="/show/{{$estate->id}}">{{str_limit($estate->building_name, $limit = 20)}}</a></td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->address, $limit = 22)}}</td>

        <td>{{str_limit($estate->price, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td class="price-hidden">{{$estate->old_price}}</td>

        <td>{{str_limit($estate->extend, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->rooms, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->entry, $limit = 20)}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

and this is the show.blade:

```
@foreach($estates as $estate)
    <tr class="even">
        <td>{{$estate->id}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->company_name, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->building_name, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->address, $limit = 22)}}</td>

        <td>{{str_limit($estate->price, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td class="price-hidden">{{$estate->old_price}}</td>

        <td>{{str_limit($estate->extend, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->rooms, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        <td>{{str_limit($estate->entry, $limit = 20)}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

what am I doing wrong here? Any idea? Thank you!
And also I have show blade that I want to just display one ID's data after click.

Comment: You have `<a href="{{route($id)}}">`, but you probably don't have `$id` identified in that scope, and that's not a valid route anyway. Try changing your URL to `href="/show/{{$estate->id}}"`

Comment: are you sure `{{route($id)}}` is not the issue? i think it should be `{{route('pagescontroller.show', $id)}}` -- ps. i'm not really sure about the name of your `Route::get('/show/{id}', 'PagesController@show');` because i always add name to my routes.. so i assume its `Route::get('/show/{id}', 'PagesController@show')->name('pagescontroller.show');`

Comment: I tried both ways but no effects :(

Comment: What happened with each?

Comment: @aynber actually when try to this: `href="/show/{{$estate->id}}"` links are came but when click the links this problem occured: `Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/show.blade.php)`

Comment: Then that would fix your first problem. That just means you need to take a look at show.blade to figure out why that's getting a non-object error.

Comment: @aynber My show.blade is look exactly the main blade. because want to ID's data retrieve. hmm...

Comment: In show -> `$estates = allestates::find($id);` and after that add conditional: `if($estates){//return the view` and in else:`}else{return view('show')->with(['estates' => array()]);`

Comment: You can use default id on the function definition: `public function show($id = 0){//now it's set at all times`

Comment: @user3647971 I updated the question mate, now I am getting this error: `Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/show.blade.php)` also added my new main.blade and show.blade. can u check it out?

Comment: change the blade template to use array representation of the model, my guess is that the underlying toArray() method gets called and data is formatted as an array. Hope this helps: `{{str_limit($estate['company_name'],$limit = 20)}}`

Comment: the whole main.blade? or just the building name? or show.blade? can u be more clear mate? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change it like this:

```
public function show($id)
{

    $estates = allestates::where('id', $id)->first();
    if($estates){
        return view('pages.show', ['estates' => $estates]);
    }else{
        return 'no records found';
    }
}
```

also route:

```
Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');
```

And

```
<td><a href="/pages/{{$estate->id}}">{{str_limit($estate->building_name, $limit = 20)}}</a></td>
```